# Is there a way to display an image grid with tick able Images in Nativescript Angular?

Tags: html, angular, nativescript

I am trying to get images into a grid on a Nativescript Angular App and then be able to tick them and move to the next page with the id's or names of those images.

i can do the image grid but i can't make them tickable. I'd be okayy with even just changing transparency on the clicked ones if possible.

Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [RadListView with GridLayout](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/item-layouts#using-listviewgridlayout) for this purpose.

Checkmark on the Image is something you have to deal with your `ng-template`. Show the checkmark based on a flag in your data item, toggle that flag upon `itemTap`.

Comment: Second.  Use a RadListView with the Grid Layout and then look at the examples for template switcher and you can have different templates for various things.  (if you need to do something for special images or etc etc).

Comment: I am using the Radlistview now and the list of images are showing using <Stacklayout><Image>  but when adding the <ListViewGridLayout><Image>  below the <ng-template> to make them into a grid, i get an error *Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling* of which i can't get around.

Comment: Can you share the Playground sample?

Comment: All you had to do was pay little more attention to the docs. `ng-tempalte` is a different element from `ListViewGridLayout`, they are standalone elements inside RadListView, not to be nested within - [Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=nolmHL&v=5)

Comment: Omg, i saw that somewhere and my brain just wouldn't accept seeing it outside that ng-template *covers-eyes emoji*. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have done the Check box on the images, and the data-items have been flagged as you mentioned, they also have id's, i want to the save the clicked items into an array. I created an array, i am pushing the clicked items to the array in the ontap of a submit button, but using Array.push(item.id) only pushes just one item, or repeats it in that array. is there a way i can do this, i'm thinking about data-forms