# Usage of ListViewGridLayout example that works

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have looked all over the internet but I cannot find a Nativescript ListViewGridLayout example that works. All seem to be outdated and they use RadListView instead of ListView.

I tried [telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/listview/app/examples/item-layouts/listview-item-layouts-grid.component.html), [A Deep Dive into NativeScript UI's ListView](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/a-deep-dive-into-telerik-ui-for-nativescripts-listview) and even saw [Is there a way to display an image grid with tick able Images in Nativescript Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289150/is-there-a-way-to-display-an-image-grid-with-tick-able-images-in-nativescript-an) but all don't work.

Here is one of the examples:
TS code:

```
filesToUpload = ["/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/NSIMG_20190424_13156.jpg",
      "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/NSIMG_20190424_131538.jpg",
      "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/NSIMG_20190423_225735.jpg",
      "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/NSIMG_20190423_22571.jpg"];
```

HTML:

```
    <GridLayout tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton columns="*">
        <RadListView [items]="filesToUpload">
            <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                <StackLayout class="garmentGrid" class="m-x-4">
                    <Image [src]="item" height="200"></Image>
                    <Progress [value]="imageUploadProgressValue[filesToUpload]" (valueChanged)="onValueChanged($event)" maxValue="100" class="">
                    </Progress>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
            <ListViewGridLayout tkListViewLayout ios:itemHeight="200" spanCount="3"></ListViewGridLayout>
        </RadListView>
    </GridLayout>
```

Comment: In recent days I have used `ListViewGridLayout` a lot, so I can at least confirm it works. Can you share a Playground sample where your issue can be reproduced?

Comment: I am officially confused. The same works on Playground but not on the local code. 
 https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=t6cCNh

Comment: @Manoj I realized that I also have to import NativeScriptUIListViewModule in my app and now it is showing something, but it's only showing the links of the images and not the actual images themselves. Do you by any chance know of any other dependencies that are required?

Comment: Where do you get these path from `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/NSIMG_20190424_131538.jpg`? This path looks like specific to your device camera, it may not exists in other devices. Like you took photos in one camera and looks for the same in another different camera. Also this looks like external storage path, so you will have to request permission for reading / writing external storage using [nativescript-permissions]https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-permissions) plugin (`android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

Comment: @Manoj Thank you for your input. NativeScriptUIListViewModule was the initial main issue but because I uninstalled the app earlier it lost it's rights to access the files so that error was being thrown silently on the logs.

Answer (score 2):

I used it like that and it works.

```
<RadListView [items]="otherDeals">
      <ListViewGridLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" itemHeight="10 0" itemWidth="100"  spanCount="3">
        </ListViewGridLayout>
      <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item" let-index="index">

        <StackLayout rows="auto" height="100%" width="100%">

          <StackLayout width="100" height="auto" (tap)="openDetails(item)">
            <StackLayout class="card-other m-5">
              some image goes here
              </StackLayout>
            <Label [text]="item.title" class="text-center h4"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

          </StackLayout>

        </ng-template>
</RadListView>
```